# jquery $.extend recursive deep copy

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to know what the first param in $.extend does? It says deep copy but what does it means?

I try it but it doesn't shows any different in the result

http://jsfiddle.net/rvbrw0p9/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var object1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
var object2 = { a: 'a', b: 2, c: 'c'};

var r = $.extend(object1 , object2 );
var r2 = $.extend(true, object1 , object2 );

console.log(r);
console.log(r2);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically there is no different from r and r2.

**But please take note on the $.extend() behaviour**  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

> **NOTE 1** jQuery.extend( target [, object1 ] [, objectN ] )

```
var r = $.extend(object1 , object2 );
// mean now we merge object2 into object1 so object1={ a: 'a', b: 2, c: 'c'}
console.log(object1) // return  { a: 'a', b: 2, c: 'c'}
console.log(r) // return  { a: 'a', b: 2, c: 'c'}
```

---

> **NOTE 2** jQuery.extend( [deep ], target, object1 [, objectN ] )

```
var objA = { k: 1, b: 2};
var objB = { k: 2, b: 'b', z:9};
var ret = $.extend(true, objA, objB); // when true as first parameter = merge recursive (deep copy) 
console.log(objA); // return { k: 2, b: 'b', z:9}
console.log(ret); // return { k: 2, b: 'b', z:9}
```

---

> **NOTE 3** What happen if we pass False or {} as first param.

```
var objA = { k: 1, b: 2};
var objB = { k: 2, b: 'b', z:9};
var ret = $.extend(false, objA, objB);
console.log(objA) // return { k: 1, b: 2}
console.log(ret) // return { k: 2, b: 'b', z:9}
```

From the above example we can see **True deep copy** will update **target** value accordingly by other **objectN** value

Comment: so shallow copy doesn't copy the nested object or inner arrays while deep copy does, is that all?